# How to set up rsync to backup from win7 to NAS?

Tags: windows-7, backup, rsync

I'd like to use [cwRsync](http://www.rsync.net/resources/howto/windows_rsync.html) to back up some files from my Win7 notebook to my Synology DS211j NAS at home. (Why cwRsync? That should be another question, but basically because I tried quite a number of solutions, and none of those seemed to be doing very well at uni-directional fast backups).

This is working:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\cwRsync\bin\rsync" -avz ^
  --log-file="C:\Users\myUserName\rsync.log" ^
  --partial ^
  "/cygdrive/c/Users/myUserName/FilesToBackup" ^
  "/cygdrive/c/BackupLocation"
```

This will nicely back up all the requested files to the specified local folder. I have my NAS as a mapped folder on my computer, say X:\data
This:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\cwRsync\bin\rsync" -avz ^
  --log-file="C:\Users\myUserName\rsync.log" ^
  --partial ^
  "/cygdrive/c/Users/myUserName/FilesToBackup" ^
  X:\\data\BackupLocation
```

gives me the following error:

```
rsync: Failed to exec ssh: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(84) [sender=3.0.6]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(600) [sender=
3.0.6]
```

I kind of thought that a mapped network drive will just act as a local folder, all the authentication stuff will be handled by windows, and rsync would just see the folder as a local one. I'm obviously wrong. How should I do this?

Comment: You might want to check out Unison: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/

Comment: @uSlackr Unison does bi-directional folder sync. I need uni-directional syncing. See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528298/rsync-for-windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok that was quick,

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\cwRsync\bin\rsync" -avz ^
  --log-file="C:\Users\myUserName\rsync.log" ^
  --partial ^
  "/cygdrive/c/Users/myUserName/FilesToBackup" ^
  "/cygdrive/x/data/BackupLocation"
```

will do it.